# Common naming conventions for option type variables and methods that return them

Tags: java, scala, guava, java-8, option-type

What are some popular ways to name option type variables and methods that return option types in order to distinguish them from their non-option counterparts?

Suppose a DAO currently has a `findById` method that returns an instance of an entity or null, if we deprecate that method and add one that returns an option type how should we name it?

Now suppose we are refactoring code to use this new method, we don't want to replace all references to the entity variable with the option type, how should we name the option type variable?

```scala
interface Dao<ENTITY ,ID> {
   @Deprecated
   ENTITY findById(ID id);

   //What naming convention should we use?
   Optional<ENTITY> maybeFindById(ID id);
}

public class MyService {
    PersonDao personDao;

    public void changeAge(final Long id,final int age) {

    //final Person person = personDao.findById(id);
    //if(person !=null)

    //What naming convention should we use?
    final Optional<Person> maybePerson = personDao.maybeFindById(id);

   if (maybePerson.isPresent()){
       final Person person = maybePerson.get();
       person.setAge(age);
    }
}
```

Comment: This article proposes to use the prefix `possible_blabla` for optional members (or accessor I suppose). https://betterprogramming.pub/useful-tips-for-naming-your-variables-8139cc8d44b5

Answer (score 8):

I don’t think that it is a good idea having two different methods here. If in doubt about the migration, keep the old one.

But there is a way to refactor the entire code in two steps:

First, change the interface from:

```
interface Dao<ENTITY ,ID> {
   ENTITY findById(ID id);
}
```

to:

```
interface Dao<ENTITY ,ID> {
   default ENTITY findById(ID id) { return newFindById(id).orElse(null); }
   Optional<ENTITY> newFindById(ID id);
}
```

I assume from your question that adapting the implementations of the interface is not an issue. Now, tell your refactoring tool to *inline* the old, now `default`, `findById` method.

Second, rename the method `newFindById` to `findById`.

This way you have migrated the `interface` to:

```
interface Dao<ENTITY ,ID> {
   Optional<ENTITY> findById(ID id);
}
```

whereas all call sites have been changed from:

```
Person maybePerson = personDao.findById(id); // may be null
```

to:

```
Person maybePerson = personDao.findById(id).orElse(null);
```

---

This way you have a clean `interface` in the first place while the other code is adapted to work as before. Then, you can go through the call sites one by one and decide whether and how they should be changed. This may take some time but since the `interface` is already clean and the naming convention problem solved, there is no need to hurry.

Note that your example method should then rather look like:

```
public void changeAge(final Long id,final int age) {
    personDao.findById(id).ifPresent(person -> person.setAge(age));
}
```

Note that in both forms, the refactored old code and the new code, there is no need to name a variable of type `Optional`, so there’s no need for a naming convention.

The refactoring requires a Java 8 capable tool, of course.

Comment: "tell your refactoring tool to inline the old, now default, findById method" doesn't you usually inline the other ways around? "Put the method's body into the body of its callers and remove the method."

Comment: "there is no need to name a variable of type Optional, so there’s no need for a naming convention." what if the optional comes from a method parameter? I know some IDEs discourage doing so but it's totally possible. In that case, you *do* need to name it. I consider this answer is totally opinionated and doesn't really answer the OP's question.

Comment: @ClintEastwood the convention is not to do it. You’re not expecting those who are discouraging it to spent time to invent a convention of how to do it, do you?

Comment: again @Holger, you're being too opinionated. There's more than *your* style of programming and they might be valid too, have you thought that? `personOpt`, `maybePerson` are a couple of reasonable names, even if you don't like naming Optional variables.

Comment: @ClintEastwood you can have as many coding styles as you want, but if your personal coding style creates the need for a naming convention, it’s up to you, to invent one. The Java maintainers, as well as the IDE developers, do not recommend such a coding style, hence, do not provide a naming convention for a discouraged coding style. Since this question is about “*common naming conventions*”, the correct answer is, there is none, regardless of which personal naming conventions the user Clint Eastwood may come up with.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is really a pretty opinion-based question, in that there really can't be any authoritative or correct answer.

That said, my preference is to just name methods that return `Optional` normally, e.g. `Optional<Foo> findById(Id id)`. The method is really no different than a method that can return `null` to mean "no result" except that the return type makes it much more explicit.

As for an `Optional` variable, I tend to just name them like `optionalFoo`... but in general I think how you name a local variable (or even field) matters a lot less than how you name a method.